# scribe no source code is available error

Tags: gwt, scribe

I'm attempting to use Scribe with GWT, but any time i switch to the designer view i get scribe errors:

> No source code is available for type org.scribe.oauth.oauthService; did you forget to inherit a required module?

I imported the scribe jar, as well as the commons codec.

I have several other errors like this, anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What is `org.scribe.oauthService`?

If you're trying to use [this class](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/scribe/oauth/OAuthService.java) then the appropriate qualified name is:

```
org.scribe.oauth.OAuthService
```

Comment: it's still not properly capitalized. Is that the error message? it should read `OAuthService` exactly like that